# Selenium: click on <li>

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following html code and I want to click on the second option "Plan b".

```
<ul class="clearfix all">
<li data-content="a" data-tab-target="tab1" class="active"><span>Plan a</span</li>
<li data-content="b" data-tab-target="tab2" class=""><span>Plan b</span></li>
<li data-content="c" data-tab-target="tab3" class=""><span>Plan c</span></li>/ul>
```

I tried to do somthing like this:

1.

```
@FindBy(css = "li:nth-child(2)")
WebElement sparpreis;
sparpreis.click();
```

2.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@class='clearfix all']/ul/li[2]")
WebElement sparpreis;
sparpreis.click();
```

My error messages:

1. org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
2. org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='clearfix all']/ul/li[2]"}

Perhaphs I should activate the second "class"?

Comment: 'Perhaphs I should activate the second "class"? ' have you tried that?

Comment: `//*[@class='clearfix all']/ul/li[2]` - it gives `NoSuchElementException` because `.clearfix.all` is the `ul` element. Try removing `ul`: `//*[@class='clearfix all']/li[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /ul is not needed, try the following:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//ul[contains(@class, 'clearfix all')]/li[2]")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared, to click on the second option **`Plan b`** you can use either of the following code block :

- **`css`**

  ```
  @FindBy(css = "ul.clearfix.all li[data-content=b] > span")
  WebElement sparpreis;
  sparpreis.click();
  ```
- **`xpath`**

  ```
  @FindBy(xpath = "//ul[@class='clearfix all']//li[@data-content='b']/span")
  WebElement sparpreis;
  sparpreis.click();
  ```